# Start jenkins in the background

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I'm using .war file to run jenkins on my server. They say use

```
java -jar jenkins.war
```

(Source: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins)
to start the server. This starts the server and shows log on screen and it is ready to use.

The only problem is when I "ctrl+c" it stops the server. I want that it should start in the background so that even though I exit from putty it should be running. I know if use native package ".deb" it will be installed as service but I want to do it using only ".war" file and not as native package ".deb". Is it even possible?

Comment: you want `nohup java -jar jenkins.war &` which will start it and detach it from the shell you started it from and put it in the background

Comment: nohup is a Linux command as far as I know. So how to do the exact same thing in windows?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just put the process in the background as suggested by @KeepCalmAndCarryOn.

`nohup java -jar jenkins.war &`

I hope this helps.