# I Can't start Jenkins in background (Address already in use)

Tags: jenkins, background-process

I am running jenkins using

```
java -jar jenkins.war -httpPort=31114
```

and it starts correctly, Now I am trying to run it in background, I found it can be done using `nohup java -jar jenkins.war -httpPort=31114 &` as mentioned here [Start Jenkins in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22292612/start-jenkins-in-the-background).

But when I terminate the session I started at the beginning and try to run it in background on the same port, I get the following error:

```
SEVERE: Container startup failed
java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:186)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at Main._main(Main.java:375)
    at Main.main(Main.java:151)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:307)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:184)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: Check whether that particular port is already in use,using this:  netstat -tulpn | grep 31114. If yes then kill the process using sudo kill -9 PID and try to start again.

Comment: There is no process using this port

Comment: Refer this, you might get some help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342207/jenkins-update-error-java-net-bindexception-address-already-in-use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried adding the command `nohup java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=31114 &` to a bash file and run the file, it worked

Answer (score 1):

`Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use`

It means jenkins already running on given port or some other process is using that port.

`netstat -nltp` Use this command to check all open ports.  Kill process if jenkin allready running on that port or if other process is using that port you can run jenkins on other port.

Below commnd you have used is correct . May be you have hit it twice .

```
nohup java -jar jenkins.war -httpPort=31114 &
```

`ps -ef | grep jenkins`. To check if jenkins is already running.

Comment: I have tried using different ports that doesn't appear in  `netstat` output and it gives the same error. but when I try to run it in the fore ground on the port 31114 it starts correctly

Comment: Not sure why you are getting error. Can you try settin port in Jenkins.xml configuration file